# Вывод console.* в терминале webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Имеется необходимость выводить console.* не в js консоли окружения, где запускается код, а в терминале с запущенным webpack-dev-server. Каким образом это лучше сделать?

С ходу подумалось, что надо сделать полифилл на console и там уже каким-то образом (каким?) колхозить перенаправление вывода в webpack. Может быть есть решения получше или что-то готовое?